# how to make chat in real time with flutter by firebase ( ios )

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, dart, chat

i made chat module for my flutter app between user and vendor for each order but in real iphones i need to back then open chat screen to see new message not real time

how can i convert it to be real time so the user or vendor no need to go back then re open chat page to see new messages

this is my codes

user chat screen

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'chat_model.dart';
import 'chatmessage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import 'package:keyboard_actions/keyboard_actions.dart';

class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String _userName;
  final String _id;
  final String _userid;
  final String _orderNo;
  final String vendorId;

  //widget.vendorId

  ChatPage(
      this._userName, this._id, this._userid, this._orderNo, this.vendorId);

  StreamSubscription _subscriptionTodo;

  @override
  _ChatPageState createState() => new _ChatPageState();
}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  static var databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  var v_id;
  var vendor_id;
  var user_id;
  var vendor_name, vendor_token;
  final TextEditingController _chatController = new TextEditingController();
  final List<ChatMessage> _messages = <ChatMessage>[];
  List<ChatModel> list_messages = List<ChatModel>();

  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  var chat_id_fr;

  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) {
    debugPrint("payload : $payload");
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
            title: new Text('Notification'),
            content: new Text('$payload'),
          ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    vendor_id = widget.vendorId;
    user_id = widget._userid;

    print(vendor_id + "ssssss");

    getDetails();
    getchat();

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var android = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var iOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initSetttings = new InitializationSettings(android, iOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetttings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

    //_firebaseMessaging.setAutoInitEnabled(enabled)
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('onLaunch called');
        showNotification("", "");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('onResume called');
        showNotification("", "");
      },
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('onMessage called' + message.toString());

        Map msg_ = message['notification'];
        String body = msg_['body'];
        String title = msg_['title'];


        setState(() {
          ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage(
            text: body.toString(),
            vendor: "vendor",
            vendor_name: "",
          );
          print("msg===" + body.toString());
          print("msg===" + body.toString());
          _messages.insert(0, message);
          showNotification(body, title);
        });

      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('all');
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings(
      sound: true,
      badge: true,
      alert: true,
    ));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print('Hello');
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {});
  }

  showNotification(String body, String title) async {
    var android = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel id', 'channel NAME', 'CHANNEL DESCRIPTION',
        priority: Priority.High, importance: Importance.Max);
    var iOS = new IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platform = new NotificationDetails(android, iOS);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .show(0, 'New Message', '$body', platform, payload: '$body');
  }

  Future<String> getDetails() async {
    FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child("vendor")
        .child(vendor_id)
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map value = snapshot.value;
      var vendor_id_fr = value['id'];
      vendor_name = value['name'];
      vendor_token = value['token'];

      //Map<String, dynamic> data = map['Data'];
      print("name " + vendor_name);
      print("id " + vendor_id);
      print("token " + vendor_token);
    });

    return vendor_id.toString();
  }

  Future<String> getchat() async {
    FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child("chat")
        .child(widget._orderNo)
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map value_ = snapshot.value;
      value_.forEach((key, value) {
        Map value_1 = value;
        chat_id_fr = value_1['chat_id'];
        var vendor_msg_fr = value_1['msg'];
        var user_id_ = value_['user_id'];
        var vendor_id_ = value_['vendor_id'];

        ChatModel chatModel = new ChatModel.fromJson(value);

        list_messages.add(chatModel);
        list_messages.sort((x, y) => x.chat_id_fr.compareTo(y.chat_id_fr));


      });

      var list_data = list_messages.toString();

      print(list_data.toString());
      // list_messages=list_messages.reversed.toList();

      int dfd = list_messages.length;

      for (int i = 0; i <= list_messages.length; i++) {
        dfd = dfd - 1;

      /*  var value = list_messages.reduce((curr, next) => curr.chat_id_fr > next.chat_id_fr ? curr : next);
        var value1 = list_messages.reduce((curr, next) => curr.chat_id_fr > next.chat_id_fr ? curr : next);
*/


        if (list_messages
            .elementAt(dfd)
            .for_value
            .toString()
            .contains("user")) {
          setState(() {
            ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage(
                text: list_messages.elementAt(dfd).msg,
                vendor: "user",
                vendor_name: vendor_name);
            _messages.add(message);
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage(
              text: list_messages.elementAt(dfd).msg.toString(),
              vendor: "vendor",
              vendor_name: vendor_name,
            );
            _messages.add(message);
            //list_messages.reversed.toList();
          });
        }
      }
    });

    return vendor_id.toString();
  }

  Future<http.Response> postRequest(String msg) async {
    var url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = {
      'notification': {'body': '$msg', 'title': 'New Massage'},
      'to':
          'fPgRVKZY56Q:APA91bHEMQy1EKHbPUraCn2tCp2th6Oah5Xx_N7b-6wLiHWjjYG7WCaRmjwstR8_YaNukwA_mwZHuCpQoYKuXL7nQBMGPH3kw58vHth7FkXuyn-keW0JnNUZhDzlgV2RA9HraeW2M4R0',
    };
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap1 = {
      'notification': {'body': '$msg', 'title': 'New Massage'},
      'to': '$vendor_token',
    };

    //encode Map to JSON
    var body = json.encode(jsonMap1);
    var response = await http.post(url,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization":
              "key=AAAAt08dld0:APA91bEY6Dtrb1x1SlAprnEYeSEUdCT0D0oq9qzlkLJDIJdB0-hVIbdKL_L6CysecmOb46gjD3lyZMKl5aGH4rY1daFYA838VMnS7SzumelXie3Vps7s8MkILRgz7Kj0QQ65Dp0uZLI6"
        },
        body: body);
    print("${response.statusCode}" + "=response=");
    print("${response.body}" + "=response=");
    return response;
  }

  void _handleSubmit(String text) {
    _chatController.clear();

    String formattedDate = DateFormat('kk:mm:ss').format(now).toString();

    var uuid = new Uuid();

    var rondm_no;
    var rng = new Random();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      print(rng.nextInt(100));
      rondm_no = uuid.v1().toString() + 'user_id';
    }

   // chat_id_fr = 0;

    if (_messages.length == 0) {
      databaseReference
          .child("chat")
          .child(widget._orderNo)
          .child('$rondm_no')
          .update({
        'vendor_id': vendor_id.toString(),
        'user_id': user_id.toString(),
        'msg': text.toString(),
        'chat_id': 0,
        'for_value': 'user',
      });

      setState(() {
        ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage(
          text: text.toString(),
          vendor: "user",
          vendor_name: "",
        );
        postRequest(text.toString());
        print("msg===" + text.toString());
        print("msg===" + text.toString());
        _messages.insert(0, message);
      });
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < _messages.length; i++) {
        int chat_id_fr = i + 1;

        databaseReference
            .child("chat")
            .child(widget._orderNo)
            .child('$rondm_no')
            .update({
          'vendor_id': vendor_id.toString(),
          'user_id': user_id.toString(),
          'msg': text.toString(),
          'chat_id': chat_id_fr,
          'for_value': 'user',
        });
      }

      setState(() {
        ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage(
          text: text.toString(),
          vendor: "user",
          vendor_name: "",
        );
        postRequest(text.toString());
        print("msg===" + text.toString());
        print("msg===" + text.toString());
        _messages.insert(0, message);
      });
    }


  }

  Widget _chatEnvironment() {
    return IconTheme(
      data: new IconThemeData(color: Color(0xFF7872c0)),
      child: new Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Flexible(
              child: new TextField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
                    hintText: "Starts typing ..."),
                controller: _chatController,
                onSubmitted: _handleSubmit,
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
              child: new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.send),
                onPressed: () => _handleSubmit(_chatController.text),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("المحادثة"), //Conversation
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF7872c0),
        ),
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Flexible(
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                reverse: true,
                itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _messages[index],
                itemCount: _messages.length,
              ),
            ),
            new Divider(
              height: 1.0,
            ),
            new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
              ),
              child: _chatEnvironment(),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

vendor chat screen

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:koni_app/Pages/UsersPages/MyOrders/Chat.dart';
import 'package:koni_app/Pages/UsersPages/MyOrders/chat_model.dart';
import 'package:koni_app/Pages/UsersPages/MyOrders/chatmessage.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'MyOrders/Vendorchatmessage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
import 'package:keyboard_actions/keyboard_actions.dart';
import 'MyOrders/vendorchat_model.dart';

class VendorAdminChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String _userName;
  final String _id;
  final String _userid;
  final String orderNo;
  final String vendorId;
  VendorAdminChatPage(this._userName, this._id, this._userid, this.orderNo,this.vendorId);

  StreamSubscription _subscriptionTodo;

/*
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF7872c0),
        title: Text("تواصل مع الادارة "),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('here the UserAdminChat page it will be '),
      ),
    );
  }
*/

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _VendorChatPageState();
  }
}

class _VendorChatPageState extends State<VendorAdminChatPage> {
  static var databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  var v_id;
  var vendor_id;
  var user_id;
  var user_name, user_token;

  final TextEditingController _chatController = new TextEditingController();
  final List<Vendorchatmessage> _messages = <Vendorchatmessage>[];

  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  List<VendorChatModel> list_messages = List<VendorChatModel>();

  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  int chat_id_fr;

  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) {
    debugPrint("payload : $payload");
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
            title: new Text('Notification'),
            content: new Text('$payload'),
          ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    vendor_id = widget.vendorId;
    user_id = widget._userid;
    user_id = widget._userid;
    // var user_Id = widget._userid;
    print("sssss" + user_id);

    getDetails();
    getchat();

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var android = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var iOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initSetttings = new InitializationSettings(android, iOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetttings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);


    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('onLaunch called');
        showNotification("", "");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('onResume called');
        showNotification("", "");
      },
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('onMessage called' + message.toString());

        Map msg_ = message['notification'];
        String body = msg_['body'];
        String title = msg_['title'];



        setState(() {
          showNotification(body, title);
          Vendorchatmessage message = new Vendorchatmessage(
            text: body.toString(),
            vendor: "user",
            vendor_name: "",
          );
          print("msg===" + body.toString());
          print("msg===" + body.toString());
          _messages.insert(0, message);
        });

      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('all');
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings(
      sound: true,
      badge: true,
      alert: true,
    ));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print('Hello');
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {});
  }

  showNotification(String body, String title) async {
    var android = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel id', 'channel NAME', 'CHANNEL DESCRIPTION',
        priority: Priority.High, importance: Importance.Max);
    var iOS = new IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platform = new NotificationDetails(android, iOS);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .show(0, 'New Message', '$body', platform, payload: '$body');
  }

  Future<String> getDetails() async {
    FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child("user")
        .child(user_id)
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map value = snapshot.value;
      var vendor_id_fr = value['id'];
      user_name = value['name'];
      user_token = value['token'];

      //Map<String, dynamic> data = map['Data'];
      print("name " + user_name);
      print("id " + vendor_id);
      print("token " + user_token);
    });
    return vendor_id.toString();
  }

  Future<String> getchat() async {
    FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child("chat")
        .child(widget.orderNo)
        .once()
        .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map value_ = snapshot.value;

      value_.forEach((key, value) {
        Map value_1 = value;

        chat_id_fr = value_1['chat_id'];
        var vendor_msg_fr = value_1['msg'];
        var user_id_ = value_['user_id'];
        var vendor_id_ = value_['vendor_id'];

        VendorChatModel chatModel = new VendorChatModel.fromJson(value);
        list_messages.add(chatModel);
        list_messages.sort((a, b) => a.chat_id_fr.compareTo(b.chat_id_fr));

      });

      var list_data = list_messages.toString();
      print(list_data.toString());
      int dfd = list_messages.length;

      for (int i = 0; i <= list_messages.length; i++) {

      /*  String lower=list_messages.elementAt(0).chat_id_fr;
        String lower1=list_messages.elementAt(0).chat_id_fr;
*/
        dfd = dfd - 1;


       /* int ss=list_messages.length-1;
        String ss=ss.toString();*/

        if (list_messages.elementAt(dfd).for_value.toString().contains("user")) {

          setState(() {
            Vendorchatmessage message = new Vendorchatmessage(
                text: list_messages.elementAt(dfd).msg,
                vendor: "user",
                vendor_name: user_name);
            _messages.add(message);
          });

        } else {
          setState(() {
            Vendorchatmessage message = new Vendorchatmessage(
              text: list_messages.elementAt(dfd).msg,
              vendor: "vendor",
              vendor_name: user_name,
            );
            _messages.add(message);

          });
        }
      }
    });



    return vendor_id.toString();
  }

  void _handleSubmit(String text) {
    _chatController.clear();
    // Vendorchatmessage message = new Vendorchatmessage(text: text);
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('kk:mm:ss').format(now).toString();
    var rondm_no;
    var uuid = new Uuid();

    var rng = new Random();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      print(rng.nextInt(100));
      rondm_no = uuid.v1().toString() + 'vendor_id';
    }

    chat_id_fr = 0;

    if (_messages.length == 0) {
      databaseReference
          .child("chat")
          .child(widget.orderNo)
          .child('$rondm_no')
          .update({
        'vendor_id': vendor_id.toString(),
        'user_id': user_id.toString(),
        'msg': text.toString(),
        'chat_id': 0,
        'for_value': 'vendor',
      });
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < _messages.length; i++) {
        chat_id_fr = i + 1;
        databaseReference
            .child("chat")
            .child(widget.orderNo)
            .child('$rondm_no')
            .update({
          'vendor_id': vendor_id.toString(),
          'user_id': user_id.toString(),
          'msg': text.toString(),
          'chat_id': chat_id_fr,
          'for_value': 'vendor',
        });
      }
    }

    /*databaseReference.child("chat").child(widget.orderNo).update({
      'vendor_id': vendor_id.toString(),
      'user_id': user_id.toString(),
    });*/

    setState(() {
      Vendorchatmessage message = new Vendorchatmessage(
        text: text.toString(),
        vendor: "vendor",
        vendor_name: "",
      );

      print("msg===" + text.toString());
      print("msg===" + text.toString());
      _messages.insert(0, message);

      postRequest(text.toString());
    });
  }

  Future<http.Response> postRequest(String msg) async {
    var url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap1 = {
      'notification': {'body': '$msg', 'title': 'New Massage'},
      'to': '$user_token',
    };

    //encode Map to JSON
    var body = json.encode(jsonMap1);
    var response = await http.post(url,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization":
              "key=AAAAt08dld0:APA91bEY6Dtrb1x1SlAprnEYeSEUdCT0D0oq9qzlkLJDIJdB0-hVIbdKL_L6CysecmOb46gjD3lyZMKl5aGH4rY1daFYA838VMnS7SzumelXie3Vps7s8MkILRgz7Kj0QQ65Dp0uZLI6"
        },
        body: body);
    print("${response.statusCode}" + "=response=");
    print("${response.body}" + "=response=");

    return response;
  }

  Widget _chatEnvironment() {
    return IconTheme(
      data: new IconThemeData(color: Color(0xFF7872c0)),
      child: new Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Flexible(
              child: new TextField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
                    hintText: "Starts typing ..."),
                controller: _chatController,
                onSubmitted: _handleSubmit,
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
              child: new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.send),
                onPressed: () => _handleSubmit(_chatController.text),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("المحادثة"), //Conversation
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF7872c0),
        ),
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Flexible(
              child: ListView.builder(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                reverse: true,
                itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _messages[index],
                itemCount: _messages.length,
              ),
            ),
            new Divider(
              height: 1.0,
            ),
            new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
              ),
              child: _chatEnvironment(),
            )
          ],
        )

        /* Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Flexible(
                child: new ListView.builder(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  reverse: true,
                  itemBuilder: (_, int index) {},
                  itemCount: 10,
                ),
              ),
              new Divider(height: 1.0),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0, right: 10.0, left: 10.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Flexible(
                      child: new TextField(
                        decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
                            hintText: "ارسال الرسالة"), //"Send message"
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Container(
                      child: new IconButton(
                          icon: new Icon(
                            Icons.send,
                            color: Color(0xFF7872c0),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {

                          }),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )*/

        );
  }
}
```

Updated Code

```
Future<String> getchat() async {

    FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .reference()
        .child("chat")
        .child(widget._orderNo)
        .onValue
        .listen((list_messages) {})
        .onData((Event event) {
        setState(() {
          if (event.snapshot != null) {
            Map<dynamic, dynamic> mapOfMaps = Map.from(event.snapshot.value);

            list_messages.clear();

            mapOfMaps.values.forEach((value) async {
              ChatModel vendor = ChatModel.fromJson(Map.from(value));
                list_messages.add(vendor);
                list_messages.sort((x, y) => x.chat_id_fr.compareTo(y.chat_id_fr));
          });
        }

      });

      var list_data = list_messages.toString();

      print(list_data.toString());
      // list_messages=list_messages.reversed.toList();

      int dfd = list_messages.length;

      for (int i = 0; i <= list_messages.length; i++) {
        dfd = dfd - 1;

        /*  var value = list_messages.reduce((curr, next) => curr.chat_id_fr > next.chat_id_fr ? curr : next);
        var value1 = list_messages.reduce((curr, next) => curr.chat_id_fr > next.chat_id_fr ? curr : next);
*/

        if (list_messages
            .elementAt(dfd)
            .for_value
            .toString()
            .contains("user")) {
          setState(() {
            ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage(
                text: list_messages.elementAt(dfd).msg,
                vendor: "user",
                vendor_name: vendor_name);
            _messages.add(message);
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage(
              text: list_messages.elementAt(dfd).msg.toString(),
              vendor: "vendor",
              vendor_name: vendor_name,
            );
            _messages.add(message);
            //list_messages.reversed.toList();
          });
        }
      }
    });

    return vendor_id.toString();
  }
```

Comment: To simplify real-time chat implementation, you could try [QuickBlox Flutter SDK](https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/flutter-quick-start) that supports 1-1 chat, group chat and video calls.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this change

use `value` instead of `once`

use this  for fetching data from firebase

```
  FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .reference()
    .child("vendor")
    .child(vendor_id)
    .onValue
    .listen(() {})
    .onData((Event event) {
  setState(() {
    if (event.snapshot != null) {
      print("data= " + event.snapshot.value.toString());

      Map<dynamic, dynamic> mapOfMaps = Map.from(event.snapshot.value);

      arrCategories.clear();

      mapOfMaps.values.forEach((value) async {
        Category category = Category.fromJson(Map.from(value));

        arrCategories.add(category);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: i used this way as you see in my updated code  but not working its same

Comment: you are able to get data, but not in the realtime right? or you are not able to fetch data even?

Comment: If it is, Please make sure your query is perfectly fine.Because I'm using the same and it's working for me

Comment: I can fetch data but not in real time , how can i make query because I’m new in firebase can you help me with that please ?

Comment: you can use either StreamBuilder view , you just need to add query reference in `stream` param
Please refer this link `https://medium.com/flutterpub/realtime-database-in-flutter-bef0f29e3378`